# How to get in MySQL defined names into php?

Tags: php, mysql

If I have a mysql query like

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data AS amount)
UNION
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data WHERE some < 50 AS something)
```

and then create an array with php like this `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC);`.

How can I now address each of the AS names. This does not work: `echo $row["amount"];`. The second question I have is why can't I use `AS something` when having a WHERE clause?

Comment: you can do $row['amount'] note the single ' not double. however your selecting a table as the amount if you want the count(*) clause to be the amount then it should be `select count(*) as amount FROM data UNION....`

Comment: Your `AS` clauses are in the wrong spots.  It's `SELECT COUNT(*) AS amount FROM data`.  `data AS amount` makes an alias for the table.  Also, I don't think `WHERE some < 50 AS something` even works.

Comment: In your example you could probably use this too but dont hold me to it `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data) as amount
UNION
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data WHERE some < 50) as something`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(
  SELECT 
    'amount1' as za_name, 
    COUNT(*) as za_count 
  FROM 
    data
) 
UNION 
(
  SELECT 
    'amount2' as za_name, 
    COUNT(*) as za_count 
  FROM 
    data 
  WHERE some < 50 
)
```

Then you can differentiate by `$row[za_name]` and get the amount `$row[za_count]`

For the second question : you can use it if you make a temp table :

```
SELECT
  tmp.za_name,
  tmp.za_count
FROM (
  SELECT 
    'amount2' as za_name, 
    COUNT(*) as za_count 
  FROM 
    data 
  WHERE some < 50 
) as tmp
```

Comment: In your first example, where does `$row[za_amount]` come from? I don´t see `za_amount` in the code.

Comment: @phpheini: I think that should be `za_count` :-P

Answer (score 1):

In a `UNION` the row names/aliases for the entire query are whatever they are in the first query.

So if you have

```
SELECT field1 AS A
UNION
SELECT field2 AS B
```

Your final result will only have an `A` field, which will have both `field1` and `field2`.

In your query, you want to alias the `COUNT(*)`, not the table.

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS amount FROM data)
UNION
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data WHERE some < 50)
```

Nor `$row['amount']` will be all of the `COUNT(*)` rows from the *entire* query.

Comment: Ok so what would I do if I want to output each A and B separately? Now I can do `echo $row[A]` and it will correctly output the amount. But `B` does not give me any output which is caused by - as you said - the fact, that everything is in A now. So is there another command to use instead of UNION?

Comment: @phpheini: You can run 2 separate queries and not use `UNION` at all.

Comment: Well thats not nice, since I have 5 parts. So I need to do 5 separate queries?

Comment: @phpheini: Or you can follow [Stephan's suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16195604/206403), and add a field to each `SELECT` with which one it is.

Answer (score 0):

in your query

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data AS amount) UNION (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data WHERE some < 50 AS something)
```

You are aliasing the table `data` to the name `amount` rather than the sub-query

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the query this way (aliases on the columns, too)

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) as amount FROM data)
UNION
(SELECT COUNT(*) as amount FROM data WHERE some < 50 AS something)
```

This way You are able to address `$result['amount']` as a result from the fetch assoc method.